# boost asio async reading and writing to socket using queue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am working on a simple TCP server that reads and writes it's messages to thread safe queue. The application can then use those queue to safely read and write to the socket even from different threads.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot `async_read`. My queue has the `pop` operation which returns the next element to be processed but it blocks if nothing is available. So once I call pop the `async_read` callback of course isn't fired anymore. Is there a way I can integrate such a queue into boost asio or do I have to completely rewrite?

Below is a short example I made to show the problem I am having. Once a TCP connection is estabilished I create a new thread that will run the application under that tcp_connection. Afterwards I want to start `async_read` and `async_write`. I have been breaking my head on this for a couple of hours and I really don't know how to solve this.

```
class tcp_connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> create(boost::asio::io_service &io_service) {
        return std::shared_ptr<tcp_connection>(new tcp_connection(io_service));
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& get_socket()
    {
        return this->socket;
    }

    void app_start()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            // Pop is a blocking call.
            auto inbound_message = this->inbound_messages.pop();
            std::cout << "Got message in app thread: " << inbound_message << ". Sending it back to client." << std::endl;
            this->outbound_messages.push(inbound_message);
        }
    }

    void start() {
        this->app_thread = std::thread(&tcp_connection::app_start, shared_from_this());

        boost::asio::async_read_until(this->socket, this->input_stream, "\r\n",
            strand.wrap(boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));

        // Start async writing here. The message to send are in the outbound_message queue. But a Pop operation blocks
        // empty() is also available to check whether the queue is empty.
        // So how can I async write without blocking the read.
        // block...
        auto message = this->outbound_messages.pop();
        boost::asio::async_write(this->socket, boost::asio::buffer(message),
            strand.wrap(boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& e, size_t bytes_read)
    {
        std::cout << "handle_read called" << std::endl;
        if (e)
        {
            std::cout << "Error handle_read: " << e.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        if (bytes_read != 0)
        {
            std::istream istream(&this->input_stream);
            std::string message;
            message.resize(bytes_read);
            istream.read(&message[0], bytes_read);
            std::cout << "Got message: " << message << std::endl;
            this->inbound_messages.push(message);
        }
        boost::asio::async_read_until(this->socket, this->input_stream, "\r\n",
            strand.wrap(boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& e, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
    {
        if (e)
        {
            std::cout << "Error handle_write: " << e.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        // block...
        auto message = this->outbound_messages.pop();
        boost::asio::async_write(this->socket, boost::asio::buffer(message),
            strand.wrap(boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    }



private:
    tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : socket(io_service), strand(io_service)
    {
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    boost::asio::strand strand;
    boost::asio::streambuf input_stream;

    std::thread app_thread;

    concurrent_queue<std::string> inbound_messages;
    concurrent_queue<std::string> outbound_messages;
};

class tcp_server
{
public:
    tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 9001))
    {
        start_accept();
    }

private:
    void start_accept()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> new_connection =
            tcp_connection::create(acceptor.get_io_service());

        acceptor.async_accept(new_connection->get_socket(),
            boost::bind(&tlcp_tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_accept(std::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> new_connection,
                       const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            new_connection->start();
        }

        start_accept();
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if you want an `async_pop` method which takes an error message placeholder and callback handler. When you receive a message, check whether there is an outstanding handler and if so, pop the message, deregister the handler and call it. Similarly when registering the async_pop, if there is already a message waiting, pop the message and post a call to the handler without registering it.

You might want to derive the async_pop class from a polymorphic base base of type `pop_operation` or similar.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me I could create a handler like this myself. As lang as I use `strand.wrap` this should work fine. One question I have though is why would I need the error message placeholder?

Comment: @JohnSmith my error. you'll want a message placeholder (std::string& ?) you'll want to pass the any error code from the last unsuccessful io read operation back to the async handler in the case where the message queue is exhausted and there is a read error.

Comment: Yes I have implemented it now. In the code it's not a string but to demonstrate with the example string was the easiest. Tommorow i'll post the code in another answer but I'll keep yours as accepted. Just for people who are wondering the same thing.